# What is the activation energy of a Daniell cell?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, kinetics, reference-request

I'm having trouble finding a posted literature value for the activation energy for the Daniell cell redox reaction:

$$\ce{Cu^2+ + Zn -> Cu + Zn^2+}$$

Where might I be able to find this information?

Comment: Electron transfer is extremely fast, that finding its rate constant is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: The equation is the summary of 2 processes ongoing on 2 different places, while activation energy applies on a single elementary reaction step.

Comment: An activation energy has a sense in a homogeneous mixture. This is not the case in a Daniell cell

Comment: @Maurice, "An activation energy has a sense in a homogeneous mixture. This is not the case in a Daniell cell" is a misconception. Electrode kinetics is very vast field and people do report activation energy, see e.g., https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp9721309